# Axlsx_Rails : How to add value into row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, axlsx

Here in below example, I want to add each array elements as separate column value between 'value1' & 'value2'. Anyone have an idea about it?

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.styles do |style|
  wb.add_worksheet(name: "Result") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ['Value1', 'Value2']
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use add_cell

add_cell(value = '', options = {}) ⇒ Cell
This adds a single cell to the row based on the data provided and updates the worksheet's autofit data.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/Row